# Grey to Colored Image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I want to improve the code, in which you can enter a grey bitmap and it will return you a colored one.

```
function ChangeBaseGrey(bitmap, color)
{
var canvas = document.getElementById("imagesColored");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dataBitmap = bitmap.data;

var r0 = (color >> 16) & 0xff,
    g0 = (color >> 8) & 0xff,
    b0 = color & 0xff;

for(var c = 0; c < dataBitmap.length; c += 4)
{
    var r1 = dataBitmap[c],
        g1 = dataBitmap[c + 1],
        b1 = dataBitmap[c + 2];

    if(dataBitmap[c + 3] > 0 && (r1 == g1 && r1 == b1 && g1 == b1))
    {
        var co = color;
        dataBitmap[c] = colorRGBBound(r0 * (r1 / 255));
        dataBitmap[c + 1] = colorRGBBound(g0 * (g1 / 255));
        dataBitmap[c + 2] = colorRGBBound(b0 * (b1 / 255));
    }
}

ctx.putImageData(bitmap, 0, 0);

var finalImage = new Image();
finalImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

return finalImage; // Colored Image Output
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a once over:

- Your indenting is off, this might be a copy paste problem into the question, consider using jsbeautify
- You never use `var co = color;`, throw it away
- `(r1 == g1 && r1 == b1 && g1 == b1)` consider that if r1 = g1 and r1 = b1, then g1 must be equal to b1 so you can use the simpler `(r1 == g1 && r1 == b1)`
- I am not sure why you update the bitmap **AND** create a new image, I would do only 1 of these for extra speeds
- `r0,g0,b0` and `r1,g1,b1` are not the most intuitive variable names..
- Consider caching the values of `colorRGBBound(r0 * (r1 / 255));` , there are only 255 possibilities for the value of `r1` and you can use the same cache for `r1`,`g1` and `b1`